# How to download data form a google datastore entity to local?

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I tried making a backup of the entity into a storage bucket and downloading that backup data file into my local but the file contains garbage data as well.

What I'm trying to do is to move a datastore entity to a cloud sql database. The plan right now is to download the datastore entity to a local and generate a .sql file from it and then use it to create the database in a cloud sql instance.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine's Datastore [import/export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) doesn't use a standard format. You might be able to read it using the methods described at [[1]](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~silver/gae.html) or [[2]](http://gbayer.com/big-data/app-engine-datastore-how-to-efficiently-export-your-data/). You can also import from those files to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore) which you can export from much easier.

Another approach is to use the Datastore API to programtically retrieve entites from Datastore to write to your SQL instance. You could even do this in [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/) which has tools for reading from Datastore and writing to SQL (via JDBC in the Apache Beam).

---

However you actually achieve the extraction, there are some extra "gotchas" to consider:

1. Datstore entities can have "ancestors". This doesn't exist in SQL. You probally want each entity type to have a separate table. Tables for child entities should have a column indicating the entity in a different table which is the parent.
2. Datastore supports array properties, while SQL does not. If you use arrays, you will need to find some way to express this in your destination schema. Typically this is achieved with a separate table and a relation. So for example if you have a "telephone_numbers" property in the Person entity with a list of numbers, you probably want a "telephone" table which has two columns - "person_id" and "telephone_number".
3. Datastore allows different entities of the same entity type to have different properties or for the same property to have different types. This is not allowed in SQL, you will need to ensure there is a uniform schema for every record in the same table.